# ASP.NET-MVC (IIS6) Error on high traffic: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, iis-6

I just launched my [tiny webapp](http://www.dudlers.com) on my humble dedicated server (Win2003)... running ASP.NET MVC, LINQ2SQL, SQL Express 2005, and IIS6 (setup with [wildcard mapping](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true))

The website runs smoothly 90% of the times. However, on *relatively* high traffic, LINQ2SQL throws the error:
Specified cast is not valid

This error is ONLY thrown at high traffic. I have **NO IDEA** how or exactly why this happens. Caching did not remove this problem entirely.

Anyone seen this problem before? are there any secret SQL Server tweaking I should've done?
Or at least, **any ideas on how to diagnose this issue?** because i'm out!

Naimi

Stacktrace (from Event Log):

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_SqlGuid()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
   at Read_Friend(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at Dudlers.Web.Models.DudlersDataContext.GetFriendRequests(Guid userId) in C:\Web\Models\DudlersDataContext.cs:line 562
   at Dudlers.Web.Controllers.BaseController.View(String viewName, String masterName, Object viewData) in C:\Web\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 39
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View(String viewName)
   at Dudlers.Web.Controllers.CatController.Index() in C:\Web\Controllers\CatController.cs:line 25
   at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(MethodInfo methodInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.c__DisplayClassb.b__8()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.c__DisplayClassb.c__DisplayClassd.b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(MethodInfo methodInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, IList`1 filters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Blankman: relatively high... not seriously high... total unique visitors per day is around 1.5k ... and most of the activity (peek time) is around 9:00 pm GMT ... which is usually when users start getting errors.

Comment: we are getting this issue with only four users

Comment: @Daniel O: Can you get the error regularly or at least somewhat regurlarly? And are you using the same DataContext for the entire request or are you creating instances for each usage?

Comment: Are you passing a connection into the DataContext's constructor and using it elsewhere or just a connection string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had a similar problem with LINQ that we get "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'" and "Specified cast is not valid."

Examples of stacktraces

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at Read_Person(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RF.Ias.Services.Person.BusinessLogic.PersonTransactionScripts.GetPersons(IEnumerable`1 personIds, Boolean includeAddress, Boolean includeContact)
   at CompositionAopProxy_5b0727341ad64f29b816c1b73d11dd44.GetPersons(IEnumerable`1 personIds, Boolean includeAddress, Boolean includeContact)
   at RF.Ias.Services.Person.ServiceImplementation.PersonService.GetPersons(GetPersonRequest request)


System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at Read_GetRolesForOrganisationResult(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at RF.Ias.Services.Role.DataAccess.RoleDataAccess.GetRolesForOrganisation(GetRolesForOrganisationCriteria criteria, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& recordCount)
   at RF.Ias.Services.Role.BusinessLogic.RoleTransactionScripts.GetRolesForOrganisation(GetRolesForOrganisationCriteria criteria, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& recordCount)
   at CompositionAopProxy_4bd29c6074f54d10a2c09bd4ab27ca66.GetRolesForOrganisation(GetRolesForOrganisationCriteria criteria, Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& recordCount)
   at RF.Ias.Services.Role.ServiceImplementation.RoleService.GetRolesForOrganisation(GetRolesForOrganisationRequest request)
```

We used to get these exceptions if we first got a exception like this "System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." or " A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)".

The first exception occur for a different instance of the DataCOntext then for all those that then are following.

After some research and asking in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780447/is-it-possible-to-gets-sql-connection-leaks-using-linq/780669#780669) , I found that the reason was that I did not dispose the DataContexts. After I started to do that, it dissappered.

Comment: Are you disposing your datacontext before creating a new instance?

Comment: Thank you. I had similar issues and this fixed me up.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like maybe a race condition, or perhaps a *rare* bug that is only *correlated* with high traffic because that when most of your requests occur.