# LINQ To SQL error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command"

Tags: linq-to-sql

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command

I am getting this error when I retrieve data from the DataContext object.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: You need to show how you use and dispose the DataConext

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that you're not declaring your DataContext as `static`. Create and destroy your DataContext on each use.

```
public MyDataClass{

    CustomerDataContext db;

    public void MyDataClass()
    {
       db = new CustomerDataContext();
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
       return db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.ID == id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this post

[Is mixing ADO.NET and LINQ-TO-SQL bad? My data layer isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094443/is-mixing-ado-net-and-linq-to-sql-bad-my-data-layer-isnt-working)

It realy depends how you store, access and dispose the datacontext.
Try to reproduce the error using a load test tool. I use jmeter. Lots of people don't know that they have this issue, because they have too little traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to close the DataReader, and you start one more DataReader on the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was converting all the `IQueryable` types associated with the query that is throwing the error to more native types before using them in another query.